# Remove-AppxPackage doesn't cleanly Remove APPX App from Windows PC

Tags: windows-10, powershell, installation

I am trying to uninstall a previously installed windows UWP App. using command below.
Below command is removing the App. from Start menu fine but the App. is not able to remove C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MyAPPNAME\ directory.

Can someone help me with this fix ?.

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name -like '*MyAPPNAME'}|Remove-AppxPackage
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate which UWP application you are trying to uninstall.

Comment: It's a private vendor App.

Comment: It shouldn't matter that the folder exists in WindowsApps.  What is the output of the command you used?  You should have been able to just right-click the application in the start menu and select uninstall.  This will allow you to install whatever version you want. Since it's not a provisioned application the existence of the folder shouldn't matter.